# Who manufactured this type of 1992 shower diverter valve?

Tags: diverter

I’m trying to replace trim on a diverter valve in our shower installed around 1992 by the previous owner. It diverts water from a fixed shower head to a handheld. We thought it was made by Kohler like everything else in the bathroom, so we stupidly threw away the old trim. Turns out it’s NOT Kohler (per Kohler customer service). Can you help me identify the manufacturer? The only things stamped on the back of the valve are “C” “DR” and maybe a “1”. No name was written on the plate.
[image: Pic of stem]

Comment: A plumbing store/shop might be able to match something that would fit.  Will need good measurements and number of teeth on that shaft.

Comment: Thank you! That’s a great suggestion.

Comment: Without a picture it would be hard for anyone to even guess.  A bit odd the one piece is not made by the same maker as the other pieces, possible maybe customer service was mistaken.